# Why j is always taking letter i from string 'kiwi'?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> a={i:j for i in "abcd" for j in "kiwi"}
>>> a
{'a': 'i', 'b': 'i', 'c': 'i', 'd': 'i'}
>>>
```

please explain how this output is coming. Why j is  alway taking i from string 'kiwi' and what does colon mean in set comprehension

Comment: The colon `:` mean this is actually a dictionary comprehension, not a set

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept and upvote! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the expression below. The way you have it written is actually a nested for loop. Since 'i' is the last letter in "kiwi", eventually all of the "j" become i.

For example when i = 'a' the following is happening {a:k}, {a:i}, {a:w}, {a:i} and stopping at {a:i}.

```
a={i:j for i, j in zip("abcd", "kiwi")}
```

Edit: Clarification of what the original code was doing.Python has a lot of short-hand syntactic sugar.

```
a={i:j for i in "abcd" for j in "kiwi"} is actually closer to this:

d = {}
for i in "abcd":
    for j in "kiwi":
        d[i] = j 
return d
```